# Correcting country names to make them match a different naming convention

Tags: r, ggplot2, country, fuzzy-comparison

I want to make a world map with ggplot as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(countrycodes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

worldmap_AMIS_Market <- map_data("world")
# Set colors
vec_AMIS_Market <- c("Canada", "China","United States of America", "Republic of Korea", "Russian Federation")
worldmap_AMIS_Market <- mutate(worldmap, fill = ifelse(region %in% vec_AMIS_Market, "green", "lightgrey"))

# Use scale_fiil_identity to set correct colors
ggplot(worldmap_AMIS_Market, aes(long, lat, fill = fill, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour="gray") + ggtitle("Map of World") + 
  ggtitle("Availability of AMIS Supply and Demand Data - Monthly") +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

As you can see the US does not light up in green, because in the `worldmap_AMIS_Market` data, the US is written as `USA`, while the vector uses `United States of America`. The same goes for Russia and South Korea. As I am going to go through this process for around 50 different datasets, I would prefer to not manually correct all countries that do no match.

Is there any way to solve issues like this? I have a couple of ideas, but not an actual solution:

1. I could do fuzzy matching, but that won't work for USA -> United States.
2. I know the package `countrycodes` can convert countries to iso codes etc, but I don't think it has the option to correct country names (https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode).
3. I could somehow collect all alternative naming conventions for all countries, and then do a fuzzy match on that. But I don't know where to get the alternative names from, and I am not sure I would be able to write the fuzzy code for this scenario anymore.

Could someone perhaps help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be `countrycode::countryname` to convert the country names.

Note: `countrycode::countryname` throws a warning so it will probably not work in all cases. But at least to me the cases where it fails are rather exotic and small countries or islands.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(countrycode)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

worldmap <- map_data("world")
# Set colors
vec_AMIS_Market <- c("Canada", "China","United States of America", "Republic of Korea", "Russian Federation")

worldmap_AMIS_Market <- mutate(worldmap, region = countryname(region), fill = ifelse(region %in% countryname(vec_AMIS_Market), "green", "lightgrey"))
#> Warning in countrycode_convert(sourcevar = sourcevar, origin = origin, destination = dest, : Some values were not matched unambiguously: Ascension Island, Azores, Barbuda, Canary Islands, Chagos Archipelago, Grenadines, Heard Island, Madeira Islands, Micronesia, Saba, Saint Martin, Siachen Glacier, Sint Eustatius, Virgin Islands

# Use scale_fiil_identity to set correct colors
ggplot(worldmap_AMIS_Market, aes(long, lat, fill = fill, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour="gray") + ggtitle("Map of World") + 
  ggtitle("Availability of AMIS Supply and Demand Data - Monthly") +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]